# How locate (NtUserUnregisterUserApiHook) function in win32k.sys with IDA

Tags: ida, windows, system-call

Im trying to understand the execution flow from `user32.UnregisterUserApiHook` to the belonged System call : `NtUserUnregisterUserApiHook` if i am right.

Currently i cant use Windbg (kernel debugger) to step through every call to see where i get.
So i try to use IDA .

I have tryed the following things (with IDA):

```
    Locate KiFastCallEntry in ntoskrnl.exe : not found
    Locate NtUserUnregisterUserApiHook in win32k.sys : not found
```

Question: how to get these functions listed [here](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/win32k_syscalls/) displayed in to IDA ?

Target OS is Windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\>md win32k
C:\>cd win32k
C:\win32k>copy c:\WINDOWS\system32\win32k.sys .
        1 file(s) copied.
C:\win32k>"c:\Program Files\IDA Free\idag.exe" -B -A win32k.sys
```

wait till *.idb and *.asm is produced in the directory

```
C:\win32k>echo :redo >wait.bat
C:\win32k>echo if not exist *.idb (sleep 30 ^& goto :redo) >> wait.bat
C:\win32k>wait.bat
C:\win32k>if not exist *.idb (sleep 50   & goto :redo )
C:\win32k>
```

search for the api in the generated asm file or reopen the idb in ida

```
C:\win32k>grep -i ntuserregisteruserapihook win32k.asm
; __stdcall NtUserRegisterUserApiHook(x, x)
_NtUserRegisterUserApiHook@8 proc near  ; DATA XREF: .data:BF99B3A4↓o
_NtUserRegisterUserApiHook@8 endp
__RegisterUserApiHook@8 proc near       ; CODE XREF: NtUserRegisterUserApiHook(x
,x)+11↑p
                dd offset _NtUserRegisterUserApiHook@8 ; NtUserRegisterUserApiHo
ok(x,x)

C:\win32k>
```

Comment: thx i will try it